# System of linear ode

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have system of equations

$
\begin{cases}
x'=a_{11}x+a_{12}y\\
y'=a_{21}x+a_{22}y\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
x'=a_{11}x+a_{12}y\\
ky'=ka_{21}x+ka_{22}y\\
\end{cases}\\
x'+ky' = \left(a_{11}+ka_{21}\right)x+\left(a_{12}+ka_{22}\right)y\\
x'+ky' = \left(a_{11}+ka_{21}\right)\left(x+\frac{a_{12}+ka_{22}}{a_{11}+ka_{21}}y\right)\\
$

Now we assume that $\frac{a_{12}+ka_{22}}{a_{11}+ka_{21}} = k$ 
Then we have 
$
\frac{a_{12}+ka_{22}}{a_{11}+ka_{21}} = k\\
a_{12}+ka_{22} = k\left(a_{11}+ka_{21}\right)\\
a_{21}k^2+\left(a_{11}-a_{22}\right)k-a_{12}=0\\
$

Now we have equations 
$
x'+ky' = \left(a_{11}+ka_{21}\right)\left(x+\frac{a_{12}+ka_{22}}{a_{11}+ka_{21}}y\right)\\
x'+ky' = \left(a_{11}+ka_{21}\right)\left(x+ky\right)\\
\frac{d\left(x+ky\right)}{dt} = \left(a_{11}+ka_{21}\right)\left(x+ky\right)\\
$ 
for each value k found by solving equation $a_{21}k^2+\left(a_{11}-a_{22}\right)k-a_{12}=0$

How this approach can be generalized to more equation than two 
This approach may also have problems with repeated roots

Comment: You method amounts to look for $k$ such that $(1, k)$ is a left eigenvector of the system's matrix $A$. Right eigenvectors such that $A u = \lambda u$ are commonly used to solve the system. In that case, a solution of the system is $u e^{\lambda t}$. General solutions can be expressed as linear combinations  of these solutions.

Comment: See Matrix differential equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation and also Matrix exponential and how to use diagonalization or Jordan normal form to compute the matrix exponential.

Comment: What's the point of $k$? You can clearly divide it out (it's obviously not 0) and solve the system of equations in a straight-forward manner.

Comment: Yes I know diagonalization approach. Jordan form is not so easy to compute for me I found this approach in russian book but i dont speak russian